# Why does explicit constructor of boost::shared_array cause an error?

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers, explicit

```
boost::shared_array<char const *> x(new char const *[n]);
```

In the line above (`n` is integer number not greater than 100) I'm creating `char const**`(`const char**`) and putting it to smart pointer `x` for arrays to be deleted when `x` is deleted. And for me it is clearly how and why this work.

```
boost::shared_array<char const *> x = new char const *[n];
```

Now lets take a look to second line. Here in my opinion we do exactly the same as in first case. Yes at first glance we may seem that here we constructing x via `NULL`(default value of shared_array constructors parameter) then calling `operator=`, but this is mistake, and as I know in this case instead of `operator=` will be called `constructor` with pointer created by `new opeartor`.

But in spit of this I'm getting `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char **' to 'boost::shared_array<T>`

The only problem I see this is the explicit constructor of `boost::shared_array<T>`. But I don't know what is the problem? Why does explicit constructor cause this error? And if the problem is not in explicit constructor, then where, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now lets take a look to second line. Here in my opinion we do exactly
>   the same as in first case. Yes at
>   first glance we may seem that here we
>   constructing x via NULL(default value
>   of shared_array constructors
>   parameter) then calling operator=, but
>   this is mistake, and as I know in this
>   case instead of operator= will be
>   called constructor with pointer
>   created by new opeartor.

That's not entirely true. Here's what actually happens in the general case. Suppose you have

```
struct A
{
   /*explicit*/ A(int){}

};

A a = 7;
```

This isn't actually equivalent to `A a(7)`. In the `A a = 7` initialization, you call 2 constructors, the constructor that takes int to create a temporary, ***and*** the copy constructor to initialize `a`. Of course this is redundant in most cases and the compiler is allowed to omit the copy-constructor call (that is explicitly mentioned in the standard) but nonetheless it ***requires*** you to have one regardless of whether it decides to omit the call or not.

```
struct A
{
   /*explicit*/ A(int){}
   private: A(A const &){}  
};

A a = 7;
```

Now this will be a compile-time error. If you add some tracing messages to both constructors, you'll most likely see that the copy constructor doesn't get called anyway, but that doesn't matter  - it must be there and accessible.

As to why `explicit` hinders you to call the above syntax must be clear now - because that constructor is called implicitly to initialize the temporary, not `a`.

HTH and Cheers, :)

Answer (score 3):

Your guess is correct.

What you're trying to do in the second line is *implicitly* calling the constructor: you want the C++ compiler to realize that there is a constructor available that accepts a `T*` and use it. However, since the constructor is marked as *explicit*, it cannot be invoked this way.

See for example the discussion at http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=20756.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the "problem" is that the `T*` constructor for `shared_array` is `explicit`. That forbids constructing with `=`.